# How to use PyParsing's QuotedString?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a string which contains several quoted values. Here is what I have so far:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Literal, printables

package_line = "package: name='com.sec.android.app.camera.shootingmode.dual' versionCode='6' versionName='1.003' platformBuildVersionName='5.0.1-1624448'"

package_name = Word(printables)("name")
versionCode = Word(printables)("versionCode")
versionName = Word(printables)("versionName")
platformBuildVersionName = Word(printables)("platformBuildVersionName")


expression = Literal("package:") + "name=" + package_name + "versionCode=" + versionCode \
                + "versionName=" + versionName + "platformBuildVersionName=" + platformBuildVersionName

tokens = expression.parseString(package_line)

print tokens['name']
print tokens['versionCode']
print tokens['versionName']
print tokens['platformBuildVersionName']
```

which prints

```
'com.sec.android.app.camera.shootingmode.dual'
'6'
'1.003'
'5.0.1-1624448'
```

Note that all the extracted tokens are contains within single quotes. I would like to remove these, and it seems like the `QuotedString` object is meant for this purpose. However, I'm having difficulty adapting this snippet to use `QuotedStrings`; in particular, their constructor doesn't seem to take `printables`.

How might I go about removing the single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the expressions with the following:

```
package_name = QuotedString(quoteChar="'")("name")
versionCode = QuotedString(quoteChar="'")("versionCode")
versionName = QuotedString(quoteChar="'")("versionName")
platformBuildVersionName = QuotedString(quoteChar="'")("platformBuildVersionName")
```

seems to work. Now the script prints the output

```
com.sec.android.app.camera.shootingmode.dual
6
1.003
5.0.1-1624448
```

without quotation marks.

Comment: Yes, `QuotedString`'s constructor take the characters to use as opening and closing delimiters, not the contents of the string.